# Haskell: [String] to IO ()

Tags: haskell, io

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to get a list of values from input and print one item out from the list each line.

```
func :: [String] -> IO ()
```

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to print out the item in the list, when the list size is just 1.

```
func [] = return ()  
func [x] = return x
```

I am getting this error message when trying to compile the file:

```
Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `String'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `x'
    In the expression: return x
```

I am completely lost and I have tried searching but haven't found anything. Thanks!

Comment: You're not actually printing anything if you just `return` a value. You need a function like `putStrLn` for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `forM_` for this:

```
func :: [String] -> IO ()
func l = forM_ l putStrLn
```

If you want to write your own version directly, you have some problems.

For the empty list, you have nothing to do but create a value of `IO ()`, which you can do with return.

For the non-empty list you want to output the line with `putStrLn` and then process the rest of the list. The non-empty list is of the form `x:xs` where `x` is the head of the list and `xs` the tail. Your second pattern matches the one-element list.

```
func [] = return ()
func (x:xs) = putStrLn x >> func xs
```

Comment: If you prefer the ['origami programming'](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/origami.pdf) style, your second implementation could be written as `foldr (\s m -> putStrLn s >> m) (return ())`, or even `foldr ((>>) . putStrLn) (return ())`, which I think is rather pretty :)

Answer (score 8):

```
func = mapM_ putStrLn
```

`mapM_` applies a monadic function like `putStrLn` to each element of a list, and discards the return value.

Answer (score 7):

you actually aren't trying to print anything, you use putStr for that.
try something like

```
print [] = return ()
print (x:xs) = do
                 putStr x
                 print xs
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually makes a lot of sense. :)

Comment: Be aware there's already a function named `print` in the Prelude: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:print